# Running a ProcessBuilder process from inside a SpringBoot application regularly hangs and does not execute the command

Tags: java, spring-boot, processbuilder

First off, this is a SpringBoot application running inside a Docker container.

The application will perform a Liquibase update for each configured tenant. In this case, 3 tenants.

What I find is that it *might* successfully execute for tenant 001 (or it may hang), and then hang on the 2nd or 3rd tenant at the same point listed before.

I have set the `ProcessBuilder` to `redirectErrorStream(true)` and `inheritIO()` but neither make any difference to the reliability of the API/command.

What am I doing wrong here?

The same command that is success for 1 tenant may hang on another, even though there is no difference in tenant state or db .. all tenants are equal at the minute.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyComponent {
  public MyComponent() throws Exception {
    
    System.out.println("RB");

    List<String> tenants = Arrays.asList("001", "002schema", "003_schema");

    for (String tenant : tenants) {

      ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
      processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
      processBuilder.inheritIO();

      System.out.println("Liquibase update: " + tenant);

      processBuilder.command(
          "/home/liquibase/liquibase",
          "--url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=" + tenant,
          "--changeLogFile=config/liquibase/changelog/root-changelog.xml",
          "--username=postgres",
          "--password=password",
          "--search-path=/home/",
          "--liquibase-schema-name=" + tenant,
          "--preserveSchemaCase=true",
          "update");

      System.out.println(processBuilder);

      Process process = processBuilder.start();

      System.out.println("Started");

      StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
      System.out.println("Buffer created");

      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(line + "\n");
      }
      System.out.println("Read lines from buffer");

      int exitVal = process.waitFor();
      System.out.println("Waited for process");
      if (exitVal == 0) {
        System.out.println("Success!");
        System.out.println(output);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.out.println(output);
      }

      reader.close();
      process.destroy();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output from the logs:

```bash
2023-03-24 22:39:00.515  INFO 30 --- [           main] c.c.c.d.migration.SpringBootApplication  : Starting SpringBootApplication using Java 17.0.6 on docker-desktop with PID 30 (/home/app-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by user in /home)
2023-03-24 22:39:00.528  INFO 30 --- [           main] c.c.c.d.migration.SpringBootApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
RB
Liquibase update: 001
java.lang.ProcessBuilder@d35dea7
Started
Buffer created
Read lines from buffer
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ## 
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ## 
##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 22:39:12 (version 4.20.0 #7837 built at 2023-03-07 16:25+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.20.0
Liquibase Open Source 4.20.0 by Liquibase
Database is up to date, no changesets to execute
Liquibase command 'update' was executed successfully.
Waited for process
Success!

Liquibase update: 002schema
java.lang.ProcessBuilder@5fbe4146
Started
Buffer created
Read lines from buffer
```

Comment: This isn't really the right way to do this. There is a [Liquibase integration](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/springboot.html) for Spring that you should use instead. Anyway, my hunch says such a long running process during bean initialization is causing some kind of timeout. I'd suggest either using the Spring Liquibase library, or try implementing `InitializingBean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have the right calls for `ProcessBuilder` but they aren't in the right order to help debug your issue.

You should print `output` before call to `waitFor` as the message may tell you the issue.

```
System.out.println("Read lines from buffer");
System.out.println(output);
int exitVal = process.waitFor();
```

Sometimes certain sub-processes wait on their STDIN eg "bash" / "cmd.exe /c" so adding explicit close to STDIN may help:

```
Process process = processBuilder.start();
process.getOutputStream().close();
```

You can also simplify the logic using `StringWriter` and try finally blocks. You shouldn't need `inheritIO`. Consider using file redirection `processBuilder.redirectOutput(File)` in case the sub-process writes a hugh mount of data to avoid OOM issues.

```
  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
  processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
  // processBuilder.inheritIO();

  System.out.println("Liquibase update: " + tenant);

  processBuilder.command(
      "/home/liquibase/liquibase",
      "--url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=" + tenant,
      "--changeLogFile=config/liquibase/changelog/root-changelog.xml",
      "--username=postgres",
      "--password=password",
      "--search-path=/home/",
      "--liquibase-schema-name=" + tenant,
      "--preserveSchemaCase=true",
      "update");

  System.out.println(processBuilder);

  Process process = processBuilder.start();

  System.out.println("Started");

  // If your app does not read it's STDIN then close it to signal end of input
  process.getOutputStream().close();

  StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
  try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
      System.out.println("Buffer created");

      reader.transferTo(output);
  }
  System.out.println("Read lines from buffer");
  System.out.println("=".repeat(80));
  System.out.println(output);
  System.out.println("=".repeat(80));

  int exitVal = process.waitFor();
  System.out.println("Waited for process exitVal = "+exitVal+ (exitVal == 0 ? " Success": " ERROR"));
```